# Only one value is assigned to all arraylist elements in constructor

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, constructor

I need to calculate mA_per_board, get total current and then assign this value to different combination of boards for future comparison and selection. The problem is when I want to assign new calculated values to the array only last value gets assigned.

Here is my constructor:

```
class boards_and_current{
   public String boards;
   public int current;

    public boards_and_current(String boards, int current){
        this.boards = boards;
        this.current = current;
    }
    public static ArrayList<boards_and_current> list_of_boards = new ArrayList();
    public void addBoards(){
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("2 boards", 0));
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("3 boards", 0));
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("4 boards", 0));
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("5 boards", 0));
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("6 boards", 0));
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("7 boards", 0));
        list_of_boards.add(new boards_and_current("8 boards", 0));
    }
   @Override
     public String toString() {
        return this.boards + "-" + this.current;
    }
}
```

Here I am getting total current for different combination of boards and assigning new values to "current" field

```
    boards_and_current list = new boards_and_current("",0);
    list.addBoards();
    for (int i=2; i<=8; i++) {
        for (boards_and_current a: list_of_boards) {
            a.current = mA_per_board * i;
        }
    }
```

the output is *[2 boards-1192, 3 boards-1192, 4 boards-1192, 5 boards-1192, 6 boards-1192, 7 boards-1192, 8 boards-1192]*

but should be something like this: [2 boards-298, 3 boards-447, 4 boards-596, 5 boards-745, 6 boards-894, 7 boards-1043, 8 boards - 1192]

Any idea why only last value is assigned to all elements in array?

Thank you in advance! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: side note: please follow the Java naming conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loops are the problem. You're going through the entire boards list twice. You don't need the enhanced for-loop. The last time, when `i` is 8, you go through entire list and you end up setting everything with that same i value. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_of_boards.size(); i++) {
  var a = list_of_boards.get(i); //You can get a using i, you don't need the enhanced for loop
  a.current = mA_per_board * (i + 2);
}
```

Comment: Your code with throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You need to check the size of `list_of_boards` in the `for` loop condition.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `list_of_boards.get(i - 2)`?

Comment: Right, I'll fix that.

Comment: thank you, it worked :) removed enhanced for-loop and used i-2